# Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration., mssqlserver after upgrade to spring boot 2

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot

I am trying to upgrade the spring boot 1.5.9 to 2.0.3, and the service failed to start with the following errors:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Method mvcConversionService in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

The service started properly in Spring boot 1.5.9.

Here the yaml file:

```
    spring:
      application:
      name: customer-crud-application

      datasource:
        url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=db-data-dev
        username: sa
        password: pwd
        driverClassName: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

      jpa:
        show-sql: true
        hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect


    server:
      port: 8080
      max-http-header-size: 65536
```

and the gradle.build

```
    dependencies {
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        compile versions.lombok
        compile('net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds')

        compile versions.spring_jdbc
        compile versions.spring_boot_starter_data_jpa
    }
```

The project was built successfully with spring boot 2.0, and I've already cleaned up the c:/Users/{user}/.m2 folder and intelliJ cache. please help!

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue. When I checked maven build log I have realized that there was an error about hibernate packages about

> "invalid LOC header (bad signature)".

I solved by deleting sub directories under

```
<user-home>\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core and recompiling my project.
```

Comment: Thanks. I deleted the <user-home>\.m2 and .gradle\caches both but still got the problem. Did you also run spring boot 2.x with MSSql Server?

Answer (score 2):

Please try make below changes in ***yaml*** file,

```
  spring:
        jpa:    
            show-sql: true
            database: MYSQL
            hibernate:
                ddl-auto: update
                dialect:
                   storage_engine: innodb
        datasource:
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename?useSSL=false
            username: user
            password: password
      
    server:
      port: 9999
```

Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following dep.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```